# is it possible to change key layout inside android application?

Tags: java, android

Can I change the layout of a bluetooth keyboard just inside my application? Or in other words rebind the keys?
For example: pressing "a" enters "s" and pressing "s" enters "a"

Answer (score 1):

You can set `setOnKeyListener()` for every `EditText` in your application, where you will handle the `KeyEvent` "a" by entering "s" to the 'EditText'. Yes, it is an ugly way but might just work.

Comment: thanks. That is what I have right now. Just hoping there is a better way!